# Finalizar processo e abrir novamente por .bat

Tags: .exe, bat

Meu problema atualmente é o seguinte, tenho um executável que tem a função de controle de acesso de funcionários, porem devido a algum problema nesse processo ele costuma parar de responder, com isso crei um bat para finalizar o processo, porem, é necessário clicar no `bat` esperar ele concluir e após isso abri novamente o executável de controle.

Queria uma ideia de como criar um `bat` que finalize o processo e após isso abra novamente o executável, isso é possível?

**.bat:**

```
taskkill /f /im ACCA.exe
```

**Caminho do executável:**

```
c:\exe\ACCA.exe
```

Desde já agradeço toda e qualquer ajuda,

Comment: Se você colocar um abaixo do outro no mesmo bat não funciona?

Comment: @WictorChaves já tentei ele simplesmente não abre, parece que ele só executa a primeira linha.

Comment: Se você precisa reiniciá-lo provavelmente ele está não está responsivo... depois do kill, quanto tempo ele demora para morrer?

Comment: @Bulfaitelo estou te aguardando no chat...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute o seguinte código `bat`:

```
taskkill /F /IM ACCA.exe
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10
start c:\exe\ACCA.exe
```

O `ping` serve como um `sleep`( ̶n̶ã̶o̶  encontrei a [função](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) de sleep no `bat`) para alguns casos de aplicações que são pesadas e precisam de um certo tempo para finalizar todos os seus serviços, o parâmetro `-n 10` indica que o sistema deve aplicar o ping no ip(*você pode usar outro ip*) uma quantidade de 10 vezes antes de abrir o executável novamente.

**@Editada**

Utilizei a o comando `timeout /t 10` citado na resposta *editada* do [Laércio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/38805/la%C3%A9rcio-lopes) para substituir o comando `ping`(usado apenas para a espera da finalização total da aplicação desejada) e funcionou, você pode substituir a linha `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10` pelo comando `timeout /t 10` caso você queira esperar 10segundos(além de que você pode encerrar a espera pressionando em qualquer tecla), tempo rasoável ao meu ver para finalizar qualquer aplicação. Recomendo utilizar o timeout, uma vez que o ping não foi feito de fato para pausar a execução. Fica ao seu critério utilizar o `ping` ou o `timeout`.

**Nota**: Não sei por qual motivo, mas ao conversar com o [Bulfaitelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/59502/bulfaitelo) no Chat, vimos que ao criar um Atalho do executável `c:\ACCA\ACCA.exe` e adicionar o caminho desse atalho ao comando `start`, o comando funcionou como esperado.

Comment: usando esse bat, ele executa a primeira linha porem na segunda ele da erro e na terceira ele não encontra o arquivo veja a tela de erro: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n58CB.png

Comment: Retira o  `*` , coloquei apenas para sinalizar e explicar no texto. vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: testei ele finaliza faz o ping porem o star não inicia o aplicativo, percebi que o erro de não encontrar é por conta do espaçamento do diretório, parece que chamando por `start C:\acca...` ele não inicia o executável https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD5l9.png

Comment: No seu diretório `C:\ACCA` existe de fato um executável chamado `ACCA.exe` ?   Porque, pelo que entendi em sua pergunta, esse executável está no seguinte diretório: `c:\exe\ACCA.exe`

Comment: Certamente é nesse ponto que ele não funciona criei um `bat` só com o `c:\ACCA\ACCA.exe`ele simplesmente não iniciar o executável, se eu for no atalho não é passado nenhum parâmetro a mais, e se for diretamente no executável e clicar ele inicia normalmente

Comment: Verifique se seu executável realmente está no diretório `c:\acca` ou `c:\exe`.

Comment: Sim está https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk41r.png

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89328/discussion-between-bulfaitelo-and-andre-filipe).

Comment: Se está no `C:\ACCA`, irei editar sua pergunta. Favor aceitá-la.

Answer (score 4):

Você já colocou o comando necessário para finalizar o programa, que é o `taskkill`, agora só falta por um `start` antes do caminho do arquivo para inicializa-lo novamente.

Seu *batch* ficaria assim:

```
taskkill /f /im ACCA.exe
start c:\exe\ACCA.exe
```

Se quiser que ele espere alguns segundos antes de iniciar o programa você pode colocar o comando `timeout /t 10` (para esperar 10 segundos), nesse caso o batch ficaria assim:

```
taskkill /f /im ACCA.exe
timeout /t 10
start c:\exe\ACCA.exe
```

Salva isso como [nomedoarquivo].bat e coloca numa tarefa agendada no Windows.

Comment: Laércio obrigado pela resposta, mas está caindo no mesmo problema na hora de iniciar o executável.

Comment: Quando o caminho tem espaços deve coloca-lo entre aspas, exemplo: `start "C:\ASC Solutions\ACCA\ACCA.exe"`

Comment: acabei movendo para um diretório sem espaços: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk41r.png

Comment: Você consegue ver o erro que dá? Coloque o comando `pause` no final do arquivo para ver qual o erro, o bat está salvo no C: se não estiver tem que colocar `C:` no início do `batch`.

Comment: chamei o bat pelo terminal ele simplesmente não da erro porem não inicia https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wca8.png

Comment: Veja no gerenciador de tarefas se ele está aberto.

Answer (score 0):

Essa linha start não funciona no Windows. O que poderia fazer é o comando C:\caminho como no executar ai vai porém nessa batch não funcionaria o kill teria que fechar o programa manualmente para inicial a contagem regressiva da linha timeout

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).